# How to install the LibreWolf Browser (incl. DRM support)?

Tags: software-installation, security, privacy, appimage, webbrowser-app

There is a newer browser, called **[LibreWolf](https://librewolf-community.gitlab.io/)**, an **independent fork of Firefox**, with the primary goals of **privacy, security** and user freedom. It is the community run successor to LibreFox.
[LibreWolf uses more than 500 privacy/security/performance settings, patches](https://librewolf-community.gitlab.io/), the browser is designed to minimize data collection and telemetry as much as possible (updater, crashreporter and Firefox's integrated addons that don't respect privacy are removed).
Distrotube gives a [video overview](https://odysee.com/@DistroTube:2/librewolf-is-a-web-browser-for-privacy:9?&sunset=lbrytv).
How do you install this browser in Ubuntu? And what about DRM support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [LibreWolf Documentation](https://librewolf.net/docs/faq/) help with detail questions and errors. The general release side is on this [Gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser). The specific releases can be found in their respective repositories:

1. **Flatpak**, the latest package can be found [on this specific Release Gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/flatpak/-/releases).
   They recommend using [**Flathub** for easier installation and updating of Librewolf](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.gitlab.librewolf-community) when using Flatpak.
   From the command line or in a Terminal:
   Install: `flatpak install flathub io.gitlab.librewolf-community`
   Run: `flatpak run io.gitlab.librewolf-community — https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.gitlab.librewolf-community`
   (If you have not setup Flatpak, see [Flatpak.org](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/).)
2. **AppImage**, the latest package can be found on [this Release Gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/appimage/-/releases).

- Download the AppImage (e.g. LibreWolf-.....x86_64.AppImage)
- Make the file executable, e.g. in the properties of the file
- Move the file to a folder you like it to be stored and run from
- Download and move the [LibreWolf-Icon](https://gitlab.com/uploads/-/system/group/avatar/5407097/icon.png) to a folder (use path for Desktop-file)
- To be able to open it from Activities or "Show Applications", generate a Desktop-file:
  Open a text file (e.g. with gedit) and add to the file:

  ```
    [Desktop Entry]  
    Name=LibreWolf  
    Type=Application  
    Exec=PATH-TO-FOLDER-WITH-APP-IMAGE/LibreWolf.AppImage  
    Icon=PATH-TO-FOLDER-WITH-IMAGE/Librewolf-logo.png  
    Comment=Secure Browser  
    Categories=Browser;Internet
  ```
- Make the Desktop-file executable, e.g. in the properties of the file
- Move the file to ~/.local/share/applications
- Now you can open LibreWolf like other applications

3. [**Debian repository**](https://librewolf.net/installation/debian/) for Ubuntu 20.04+ and Min 20.04
   *Change this command to choose a distro manually.*

   distro=$(if echo " bullseye focal impish jammy uma una vanessa" | grep -q " $(lsb_release -sc) "; then echo $(lsb_release -sc); else echo focal; fi)

   wget -O- https://deb.librewolf.net/keyring.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/librewolf.gpg

   sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/librewolf.sources << EOF > /dev/null
   Types: deb
   URIs: https://deb.librewolf.net
   Suites: $distro
   Components: main
   Architectures: amd64
   Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/librewolf.gpg
   EOF

   sudo apt update

   sudo apt install librewolf -y
4. **Manual Compilation**
   See for more details [on the project page on Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/linux).
5. **Binary Tarball**
   LibreWolf is available as a binary tarball. Check out the [releases pages](https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser) [on Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/appimage/-/releases) for downloads.

If you find any **bug or problem**, please report it on [the project page on Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/linux/-/issues) and/or help with programming.

Some tips regarding **settings** you can find [here on the project page](https://librewolf.net/docs/settings/).

The **configuration** files you can find here: /home/USERNAME/.librewolf/

Integrated and suggested **add-ons** are [listed on this Gitlab page](https://librewolf-community.gitlab.io/docs/addons/).

**How to get DRM Compatibility**
Digital rights management (DRM) is enforced off by default (this is needed for Netflix and similar); you can enable it with the following instructions:

- Open librewolf.cfg  (e.g. `sudo gedit /usr/lib/librewolf/librewolf.cfg`)
- Under the section `Section: User Settings`
  -- Comment the active lines with `//` under the subsection `User Settings: DRM/CDM - Main`
  -- Comment the active lines with `//` under the subsection `User Settings: DRM/CDM - Widevine`
- Restart LibreWolf then open `about:preferences` and enable `Play DRM`... under general section
  -- LibreWolf will download Widevine and enable it (under `about:addons` plugins section) you can force the download by clicking Check for updates under the tools button

[**Browser doesn't restore session after restart**](https://gitlab.com/librewolf-community/browser/arch/-/issues/14)
Preferences:

1. Check `Restore previous session`
2. Privacy & Security: Scroll to History, to the right from Clear history when LibreWolf closes find button `Settings`... and uncheck: `Browsing & Download history`

**Save passwords**
Activate `Restore previous session` (see above) can help.
More changes are not really possible with AppImage. It is recommended to use a dedicated open source, end-to-end-encrypted password manager, more about this in this [Reddit thread.](https://www.reddit.com/r/LibreWolf/comments/le8r72/save_passwords_and_restore_previous_session/)

Comment: AppImage is surely the easiest way.

Comment: some pages there 404 now. at https://librewolf.net/installation/linux/ they recommend appimage, and using appimage launcher to integrate .